# Keyboard-independent way of detecting shift+digits

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to be able to detect when the user press digits. This part is working with the `<Key-#>` bindings (code below).
But i need to react differently when the users press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>digits</kbd>. I've tried `<Shift-#>` but it doesn't work because pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>digits</kbd> will create events corresponding for chars like `!`, `@`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `¨`, `&`, `*`, `(`, `)`

One could "*listen*" for those chars but problem is their position is not the same in all keyboards.

*QWERTY - English*
[image]

*AZERTY - as used in parts of Belgium*
[image]

Not only different layouts (*QWERTY*, *AZERTY*, *DVORAK*, etc) differ but even two different *QWERTY* keyboards can be different depending on your locale. (My qwerty keyboard has an `¨` in the same key as `6` as oposed to `^` as seen in the picture)

So "*listening* for stuff like `exclam`, `dollar`, `ampersand` and etc is a keyboard-dependent way of detecting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>digits</kbd>.

**Question: how can i do it in a keyboard-independent way?**

```
frame .f -padx 50 -pady 50
focus -force .f
label .f.digit_label -text "Digit:" -padx 50 -pady 20
label .f.keypress_label -text "KeyPress" -padx 50 -pady 20
pack .f
pack .f.digit_label
pack .f.keypress_label
bind .f <Key-1> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-2> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-3> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-4> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-5> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-6> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-7> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-8> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-9> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Key-0> {::digit_press %K}

bind .f <Shift-1> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-2> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-3> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-4> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-5> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-6> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-7> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-8> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-9> {::digit_press %K}
bind .f <Shift-0> {::digit_press %K}
bind all <Escape> {exit}
bind all <KeyPress> {::keypress %K}


proc ::digit_press {str} {
    .f.digit_label configure -text "Digit: $str"
}
proc ::keypress {str} {
    .f.keypress_label configure -text "KeyPress: $str"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when writing software, you want the cooked symbolic names of keys or the characters that they encode. Not in your case. Tk mostly hides the low level from you, but you can get at it if you're prepared to work at decoding it. In particular, if you do this in a raw wish:

```
bind . <Key> {
    puts "%A:::%s:::%k:::%K"
}
```

Then you can press keys and see what you get. Be aware that there's no actual guarantee that these will be the same for all keyboards! On mine (UK layout), pressing <kbd>1</kbd>,  <kbd>2</kbd>,  <kbd>3</kbd> followed by shift and the same three keys prints this:

```
1:::0:::26:::1
2:::0:::27:::2
3:::0:::28:::3
{}:::0:::68:::Shift_R
!:::1:::26:::exclam
@:::1:::27:::at
£:::1:::28:::sterling
```

As you can see, the `%k` field reports the keycode that does *not* change on shift status, and the `%s` field becomes 1 when the shift key is down (it's a bitmap, so use `[expr {%s & 1}]` to test that). You'll have to throw events away too.

Comment: You will need to require your users to do a one-time setup task to press the 0-9 number keys so that you can record the corresponding keycodes for their machine.   My keyboard returns a keycode of 10 for the '1' key.

Comment: @BradLanam yes, thats exactly what i'm trying avoid.

Comment: @Donal Fellows Yes the %k fields seems to be the solution. Regarding the `%s` is there a better documentation for it other than the [manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm#M38)? It doesn't describe in detail what this *state* is, how to use it and etc

Comment: Wow, very different on a Macbook: `1:::0:::49:::1` and `{}:::1:::131072:::Shift_L` and `!:::0:::33:::exclam` -- the state is zero for shift+1. Also, I was using the _right_ shift key.

Comment: Can't i use  `bind all <Shift-KeyPress> {::shiftdigit %k}` and inside the proc get the digit by `[expr {$keycode-48}]`? Seems to be keyboard independent.

Comment: I don't know if there's any common definition of what keycodes are. I know that they're the raw information in keyboard events (not sure what you get with input methods) and that Tk maps that to characters for you (handling keyboard remapping events for you), but the details with actual different keyboards are just things I don't know.

Comment: @HenriAugusto A quick test of keycode mapping for keys `1`..`0` on my machine gives `%k` as: 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 30, 34, 36, 33, 37. Yes, not contiguous. Not ordered. I have no idea why. (32 and 35 are `-` and `=` respectively)

Comment: Oh, i see. Definitely keyboard-dependend. I get keycodes from 48 to 57.

Comment: @DonalFellows just out of curiosity what is your keyboard and what OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Win 10 with a PT-BR keyboard. I've changed the [functional layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Mechanical,_visual,_and_functional_layouts) in windows settings and tried lots of combinations between QWERT/AZERTY/DVORAK/etc and languages. The keycodes for [0-9] were always between 48 and 57 so i wonder if `%k` is mechanical-layout-dependent.

Comment: That was testing with a late 2019 macBook Pro using UK layout _running a build with X11_ (because that was the build of Tk I had conveniently available). If you're only really going to run on X11, you can [use `xmodmap -pk`](https://askubuntu.com/a/245363/541999). With a _very_ old native build, I get totally different keycodes (that appear to be two values packed in a word; the upper half-word seems to be the relevant one).

Comment: This all appears to be a bigger pain than I thought.

Comment: haha yes, definitely a obnoxius and tricky one! I needed it for a [cross-platform software](https://github.com/pure-data/pure-data) so i guess i'll probably just have to use other bindings.